# MySql: Combination of all records where SUM of those records is 9

Tags: mysql

lets say i have a table with only 1 field in it called ID. The ID is numeric field and records are from 1 till 5.

**TEST_TABLE_ID**

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is it possible to write a query that would output all combinations of records where sum(ID)=9?

Like:
`1 3 5`;
`1 5 3`;
`2 3 4`;
`2 4 3`;
`3 1 5`;
`3 5 1`;
`3 4 2`;
`3 2 4`;
`4 5`;
`4 3 2`;
`4 2 3`;
`5 4`;
`5 3 1`;
`5 1 3`
etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a cross join approach:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID, t3.ID
FROM yourTable t1
CROSS JOIN yourTable t2
CROSS JOIN yourTable t3
WHERE t1.ID + t2.ID + t3.ID = 9
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's not what i am looking for. As you see the correct answer is also 5 and 4 ... which would be left out with your solution. And this was just an example with 5 records. The actual problem has 34 records in total ... so the possible result of combinations could be 34*33*32*31*...*3*2*1 in theory ...

but building it like that and test with increasing cross joins might bring me to the solution.

Comment: And just like that your solution gave me a result :) i only needed 1 cross join :)
Thank you so much!!!